# Mouse events and action events

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, mouselistener

On a Java AWT button I can add both mouse listener and action listener. So can I say that the mouse events are hardware interrupts as they are generated by mouse and action events are software interrupts as they are generated when the state of the button is changed?

Comment: An `ActionEvent` is generated when a `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` event is received on the button.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. Java has events instead of interrupts. The main reason for the distinguishing between mouse and action events is that there are other ways to click a button other than actually clicking on it. You could direct focus to the button and then press the space bar, at least on Mac.